# Using "<" or ">" as part of parameter value in angular translate and displaying in textarea as ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have an angular translate string with a parameter. The parameter name can also be of the form `<test>`. When the translate is displayed in a textarea, we end up seeing `&lt;test&gt;` instead of `<test>`. Is there a way to make it appear as `<test>`.

The angular translate file is:

```
"MESSAGE_KEY": "Display {someParam} displayed",
```

The message is:

```
var message = $filter('translate')('MESSAGE_KEY',
                {someParam: '<test>'},
                'messageformat');
```

What I see in the textarea when I use the message as the ng-model is

```
&lt;test&gt;
```

Note 1: It will be tricky to use the contenteditable for us for various reasons
Note 2: We have set the sanitization strategy to be as below

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters', 'sanitizeParameters');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Have included a working snipped. Run the code snippet to view the working sample.

```js
var translations = {
  MESSAGE_KEY: "Display {{someParam}} displayed"
};

var app = angular.module('AsdDTestApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', translations);
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
  // Enable escaping of HTML
  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sceParameters');
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.message = $filter('translate')('MESSAGE_KEY', {someParam: '<test>'}, 'messageformat');
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="AsdDTestApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.17.0/angular-translate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
    Here is my input box:
      <input type="textarea" ng-model="vm.message">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You need tot  use

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sceParameters');
```

instead of

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters', 'sanitizeParameters');
```

> sanitize: sanitizes HTML in the translation text using $sanitize
>
> escape: escapes HTML in the translation
>
> sanitizeParameters: sanitizes HTML in the values of the interpolation parameters using $sanitize
>
> escapeParameters: escapes HTML in the values of the interpolation parameters
>
> sce: wraps HTML in $sce.trustAsHtml(value)
>
> sceParameters: wraps HTML in the values of the interpolation parameters in $sce.trustAsHtml(value)

[more on escaping variables in angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security)

Comment: Thank you. Two things - Firstly since the "<" or ">" is part of the parameter value, I would have thought that the escapedParameters is the appropriate strategy to use. Anyway, I did try the 'escape' and I still see the same results as what I did with my original code (where I am using 'escapeParameters'). Please let me know if you have any comments. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Sanitization using `sceParameters` would work. Have edited my answer and have added a code snippet of a working example.